# Netbeans GUI Builder

Tags: java, layout, user-interface, netbeans

I have a question about Netbeans GUI Editor.
I created this test application containing a MenuBar using the GUI Editor. However I need to Add another swing component (Let say a Jbutton) to the frame that contains the MenuBar directly from the code and not using the GUI Editor.

I Succeeded in adding the Jbutton but I found that the only way to do it is to change the layout from the code. The result was not what I expected since the menuBar added by the GUI builder changed it layout also.

So briefly I want a way to add The Jbutton from the code without affecting the original components added using the GUI Builder.

Comment: I am not sure if there is a specific way to do that, as there are many ways, it depends on your design and what layout manager to use to comparable with your design. It's impossible to say `"Use this layout"`

Comment: Did you change the layout in Netbeans or in your code, manually?

Comment: in order for the button to appear after running the application I must  set the Layout to FlowLayout otherwise it wont appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GUI builder uses the Group layout. if you want to preserve the layout of the original components you need to stick to this layout. Codeing by hand in this layout is awkward but the following link will help.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/groupExample.html

You'll need to add your button, using the addCompenent method, to groups in both the horizontal group and the vertical group.

Good luck!

Comment: Problem Solved by using the Coping Netbeans generated code to a new java file and modifying it by adding the JButton using GroupLayout (vertical/horizontal) as suggested by DonaldAnderson